# How to slide a vertex group to make new edge loop?

Tags: modeling

[image: What I want to do?]

I want to slide that vertex group like shown to make 2 new edge loops connecting to each other like a cylinder. Or transforming these 4 vertices into one edge loop would work out. How can I do so?

[image: Another perspective]

Here in another perspective ^

[image: What I want 2]

That's what I really want on front ortho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the *Loop Cut and Slide* operator <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keyboard shortcut to manually place a cut on each side.

[image: Loop Cut and Slide]

Or alternatively use the *Bevel Edge* operator on the whole existing edge loop <kbd>CtrlB</kbd>. Make sure you set the *Bevel Profile* factor to `1` so your current edge loop wont be moved

[image: Bevel Edge]

Comment: Bevel won't work because the selected vertices don't make an edge loop. There are only 4 vertices, consider that. But slicing would work in that case!

Comment: Loop cut should work fine in that case then, no?

Comment: Not in this particular model. Loop cut, cuts all the way up :c Actually what I really need is to extend these vertices into a loop. I edited the question check the 3rd screenshot, you'll get me cleaner

Comment: What you have there is a non manifold mesh, your edges belong to more than two faces at the same time. I don't think there is a direct way to do what you want, my advice is to erase that part of the mesh and remodel it correctly. If you object is totally symmetrical consider using a mirror modifier instead to make it easier for you