# Loop cut (ctrl+R) and space cuts in the same operation

Tags: edges

I am wondering if Blender has some hidden function or anything that can make even space between edges when adding new edge loops with ctrl+R. Or even space after adding them, like if it was a mirror effect of the selected edge, so that the other edge moves the oposite way if you know what I mean.

I made a GIF from 3ds max that shows the method I am looking for:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVx9D.jpg

Figured out with help from Blender discord community that I can select my 2 edges and scale with Z, but this only works if the axises are perfectly alligned. What if I got something bent with different size like a cone, the vertices of the edges would not follow the edge with this method :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Ctrl + R then mouse wheel to add additional Loop Cuts.

Comment: Ya that is not the answer thoug. Ctrl+R > mousewheel is just how to add more edges. But what I am asking for is how to make even space between those edges, different amount of space in other words. Like in the GIF

Comment: In your example you could add two Loop Cuts set them in place and with both Loop Cuts selected press "S" "Z" to scale them on the z axis.

Comment: Ye, thats also what I wrote :D But I am trying to figure out, how do to it in every situation where I want two new edges, as the example I wrote above, if I use this method on a cone, with 2 edge loops in the middle, the selected edges wont follow the actual cone, the edges will scale straight up and down :(

Comment: @Socka in the future please use the tools on this site to make the images visible as part of your post. see: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Oh, thought it was enough to just post a link

Comment: Z isn't the only axis you can scale along. There are also normal axes, view axes etc. You can scale along normal Z or whatever axis, or align viewport with some face and scale along view Z axis. Or you can press G twice and use edge slide to move edge along normals (not all times solution but will work in this case)

Comment: But moving with GG I have to do it one edge at the time, that wont get an precise even space?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76628/how-to-outset-from-edges-vertices/76651?s=2|38.2469#76651

Answer (score 5):

Use the *Bevel* operator after loop cutting.

Make a single loop cut were you want the symmetrically spaced loops to happen, then bevel with zero segments.

This will virtually replace the single centered loop with two evenly spaced loops. The advantage is it works well in non axis aligned faces, uneven loop widths and allows adding more loops.

[image]

Also see related [How to slide a vertex group to make new edge loop?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57259/how-to-slide-a-vertex-group-to-make-new-edge-loop/) and [How to outset from edges/vertices?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76628/how-to-outset-from-edges-vertices/)

Comment: Thanks, this seem to be as close to the answer as possible. There is no function for this in Blender when I have more than one loop right?

Comment: I am not aware of any, as far as I know. You can however subdivide several rings at the same time, or bevel several edge loops simultaneously

Comment: Ya good to know! :)